# Loop through select dropdowns in a form

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, dropdown

Can someone help me loop through all the select dropdowns in a form and return the value selected? The number of dropdowns could vary for each form. Here's my form:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" id="select_distributor_form">
{{#each context.supplier}}
  <div class="form-group">
    <label  class="col-sm-2 control-label">{{supplier_name}}</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <select class="form-control">
          <option selected disabled>Select distributor</option>
          {{#each ../context.distributor}}
            <option value="{{distributor_id}}">{{distributor_name}}</option>
          {{/each}}
        </select>
    </div>
  </div>
{{/each}}
</form>
```

So far, I have come up with:

```
  $("select option:selected").each(function(i, obj){
      alert($(this).val());
  });
```

However, this will loop through all the dropdowns on the entire page. I only want to loop through dropdowns in the form.. Can someone help?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `$('#select_distributor_form select').each() {`

Comment: Use a [descendant selector](https://api.jquery.com/descendant-selector)